# Работа с исключениям при достижении лимита постов

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api

Есть скрипт, который отправляет в ВК посты в 2 группы. Сообщения разные и количество их тоже разное, но наступает момент когда в одной группе лимит постов заканчивается и скрипт прекращает работать с ошибкой 214.

Как и что прописать чтобы скрипт продолжал работать со второй группой?

```
    if data1:
        api.wall.post(owner_id='-1', message=text1)
    if data2:
        api.wall.post(owner_id='-2', message=text2)
```

Ошибка:

> vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 214. Access to adding post denied: you can only
>   add 50 posts a day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def wall_post(**kwargs):
    try:
        api.wall.post(**kwargs)
    except vk.exceptions.VkAPIError as e:
        if e.code == 214:
            #print('Warning: {}'.format(e.error_msg))
            pass
        else:
            raise

if data1:
    wall_post(owner_id='-1', message=text1)
if data2:
    wall_post(owner_id='-2', message=text2)
```

PS у меня нет VK account'а, поэтому код не протестирован